# strange python error where the compiler-error changes the case of a letter

Tags: python, compiler-errors, pycharm

I got a python error where it shows the logger object as Logger, changing the lower-case "l" to an "L".
here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/stocks/stock-watchlist/Notes.py", line 195, in <module>
logger.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
AttributeError: 'Logger' object has no attribute 'basicConfig'
```

Language: Python
IDE: PyCharm
PyCharm 2021.1 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-211.6693.115, built on April 6, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.10+9-b1341.35 x86_64
VM: Dynamic Code Evolution 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 12.4
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 8
Non-Bundled Plugins: IdeaVIM (1.9.2), Key Promoter X (2021.1.1), cn.haojiyou.CodeGlance3 (2.0.1), com.mallowigi (36.0), com.markskelton.one-dark-theme (5.6.0), com.nasller.CodeGlancePro (1.3.8-Last2021.3.x), com.tabnine.TabNine (0.7.2), io.acari.DDLCTheme (78.2-1.1.1), io.unthrottled.amii (0.14.1), zd.zero.waifu-motivator-plugin (2.2.0), izhangzhihao.rainbow.brackets (6.24), org.exbin.deltahex.intellij (0.2.6)

Comment: `Logger` is the _type_ of the object, not its _name_.

Comment: Did you mean to do `logging.basicConfig`?

Comment: @JohnGordon Why is the type `Logger` and not `logger`? (logger is the name I assigned to `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`

Comment: Because `getLogger()` returns an instance of the `Logger` class.

Comment: ohh, that make a lot more sense, so my variable named logger just happened to have the same name as the Logger class, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jhon Gordon mentioned:

> `Logger` is the *type* of object, not its *name*.

The `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` uses the `getLogger()` method which has the same name as my variable explaining why it appeared like the compiler-error changed the case of the letter, it was pure coincidance.

Comment: I think what I meant was that in ```getLogger()``` it gets a Logger which is the uppercase version of my ```logger``` hence why I thought it was referencing my ```logger``` but changing the case, coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

It should be [logging.basicConfig](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig)